# Cannot call the shell script on the shared repository in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am testing out an idea, so I created a shared repository called `DevOps.Shared`, which has some templates and a shell script. The idea is to have shared template files and run these yaml files as a step from remote repository. I managed this, but for some reason I cannot call the shell script on the `DevOps.Shared` repository.

Shared pipeline has this structure:

[image: devops shared pipeline structure]

And the Build.yaml file is the job that will run the shell script:

```
# Build.yaml file on DevOps.Shared pipeline
parameters:
  buildType: ~   #dotnet, flutter
  projectName: ~ #Project name
  gitRepoUrl: ~  #Git repo URL to checkout
  buildTarget: ~ #file or directory 
  

jobs:
  - job: BuildTargetStep
    displayName: Build ${{ parameters.buildType }} component
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            ls -l
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: Validate Build Type
        inputs:
          targetType: 'filePath'
          filePath: Templates/Build/scripts/validate_build_type.sh
          arguments: >
              -t ${{ parameters.buildType }}
```

And the pipeline that calls this shared repository only references the repo this way, and calls the jobs from that repo.

```
# Test.yaml (pipeline file on another repo)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: DevOps_Shared
    type: git
    name: DevOps.Shared/DevOps.Shared
    ref: task/ground-work

stages:
  - stage: BuildAndAnalyse
    displayName: Build and Analyse
    jobs:
      - template: Templates/Build/Build.yaml@DevOps_Shared
        parameters:
          buildType: 'dotnet'
          projectName: 'test'
```

What happens is it says it can't find the script because it is trying to execute that script on the working directory, but obviously it's not on the agent because it's never checked out. I thought I could reference like this, what am I missing here? Cheers.

[image: ADO Pipeline shared script fails]

Edit: "Bash" and "Validate Build Type" are the steps from the shared pipeline.

Edit 2: Both repositories are on the same ADO organisation and pipeline A has the permission to consume the stuff from shared repo.

Comment: ls -l does not show anything else besides the checked out branch of the main project.

Comment: The first checkout step, does it checkout the repo itself or the `devops.shared` repo?

Comment: @Sibtain it checks out itself, I was wondering whether I need to explicitly checkout the shared repo?

Comment: Yes, exactly. when using `checkout: self` in a template, it doesn't care where it's located. it will checkout the repo where pipeline is triggered so you can pass in the repo name to the devops.shared repo and then do `checkout: DevOps_Shared`

Comment: Ah fair enough, it seems a bit weird to me though, as it can still call the template step from the shared repo without checking out, but it can't find the script file because it's not checked out. I'll give this a go now, cheers.

Comment: Yes that's true, I have added an answer which I tested on my end. You can go over it in case you get stuck. Feel free to upvote/accept if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mentioned in the comments, you need to explicitly checkout the `DevOps.Shared` repo instead of `checkout: self`. Below is a working example that I tested out:

**build.yml**

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: ServiceB
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/main
    name: ServiceB

stages:
  - stage: BuildAndAnalyse
    displayName: Build and Analyse
    jobs:
      - template: my-template.yml@ServiceB
        parameters:
          devopsRepo: ServiceB
```

**my-template.yml**

```
parameters:
  devopsRepo: ''

jobs:
  - job: BuildTargetStep
    displayName: Build component
    steps:
      - checkout: ${{ parameters.devopsRepo }}
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: Validate Build Type
        inputs:
          targetType: 'filePath'
          filePath: Build/scripts/hello.sh
```

**Working demo:**

[image]

Also notice this from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path):

> If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is
> checked out into directories named after the repositories as a
> subfolder of s in (Agent.BuildDirectory). If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is
> C:\agent_work\1 and your repositories are named tools and code, your
> code is checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s\tools and
> C:\agent_work\1\s\code.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked as you mentioned. Many thanks for the help!